# Convert Json to C# class using IEnumerable<>

Tags: c#

I have a Json which looks like this...

```
{
  "steps": [
    {
      "stepsType": "runWizard",
      "wizardType": "cv2.0Server",
      "config": {
        "mode": "add",
        "resourceName": "cv2.0 Server",
        "activeDbPrimaryServer": {
          "serverName": "JJH3M005A",
          "serverAddress": "JJH3M005A.microsoft.info"
        },
        "activeDbCatalog": "cv2.0Database",
        "activeDBUserId": "user",
        "activeDBPassword": "password",
        "activeIntegratedSecurity": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have created a model like this...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Microsoft.Database.Configuration.Model
{
    public class ClusterConfigurationModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<ClusterConfigurationModelStep> Steps { get; }
    }

    public class ClusterConfigurationModelStep : ClusterConfigurationModel
    {
        public string StepType { get;  }

        public string WizardType { get;  }

        public IEnumerable<ClusterConfigurationServerConfig> Config { get;  }     
    }

    public class ClusterConfigurationServerConfig : ClusterConfigurationModelStep
    {
        public string Mode { get; }

        public string ResourceName { get; }

        public IEnumerable<ClusterConfigurationDbPrimaryServer> ActiveDbPrimaryServer { get; }

        public string ActiveDbCatalog { get; }

        public string ActiveDbUserId { get; }

        public string ActiveDbPassword { get; }

        public string ActiveIntegratedSecurity { get; }
    }

    public class ClusterConfigurationDbPrimaryServer : ClusterConfigurationServerConfig
    {
        public string ServerName { get; }

        public string ServerAddress { get;  }
    }
}
```

Is this correct I am trying to create a custom json convertor using,

1. AbstractJsonConverter
2. JsonConverterFactory with an Interface
3. JsonConverter with an Interface

I am new to C#, just want to know whether the model I have created is correct or do I need some modification?

Comment: Paste your JSON in to https://app.quicktype.io/ . Use that model.

Comment: I did, but it supports only List or Array, I wanted to ask in perspective of IEnumerable...

Comment: Change it to `IEnumerable` - does it still work (it likely will)? My point is you shouldn't need `AbstractJsonConverter` etc etc.

Comment: List and array are IEnumerable. They can be used "anywhere you see the IEnumerable logo" . Use List if you plan to edit/add to your data after parsing or array if you don't. You can't add to an IEnumerable; it will need to be casted to whatever editable thing is the implementing type inside it

Comment: Follow mjwills' advice - have QuickType make your model and just use what they give you. You can still return your List<Steps> From a method declared to return IEnumerable<Steps> because List<T> implements IEnumerable<T>

Comment: @CaiusJard Thanks, I will follow the same approach

Comment: Welcome! Whether you're new to C# or old, use all the help you can get- QuickType is brilliant and saves so much time doing tedious POCO creation.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need not to have inheritance for every single class. For example (after removing inheritance):

```
public class ClusterConfigurationModelStep : ClusterConfigurationModel
{
    public string StepType { get;  }

    public string WizardType { get;  }

    public IEnumerable<ClusterConfigurationServerConfig> Config { get;  }     
}
```

Second, you may want to have `[JsonProperty("json_key_name")]` from `Newtonsoft.Json` or `[JsonPropertyName("json_key_name")]` from `System.Text.Json` for mapping JSON keyfield name to class's variable. It is by default using camelCase in C#.

Comment: Both newtonsoft and system json understand that c# is PascalCase and Json is camelCase. They do not need to be instructed (via attribute) of this difference in order to be able to parse "someProperty" -> SomeProperty. There isn't any indication that this model is being serialized

Answer (score -1):

You should avoid using `IEnumerable<T>` for fields and properties, use a `T[]` array or an `IList<T>` instead.

The reason for this is that an enumerable is an interator that contains state, it contains a reference to the current item being pointed to. This means that it can only be consumed once, and then you can not enumerate the contents again.

Instead, you usually want to create a list instead and then enumerate that list multiple times in multiple places in your code.

Comment: I don't agree with this. Are you getting confused with an Enumerator?

Comment: You don't want to use `IList`, as a general rule (since it has the lovely quality of maybe you can add to it, or maybe you can't). `IReadOnlyList` is likely the best choice for the OP here.

Comment: See also ["properties should not return arrays"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/210922/ca1819-properties-should-not-return-arrays-does-this-happen-only-with-arrays)

Comment: I agree with @CaiusJard, especially since `IEnumberable<T> variable = new T[n]` is perfectly valid. And you can definitely enumerate a IEnumberable more than once, each invocation will create a new Enumerator that points to the head of the collection.

Comment: No, I'm not getting confused with ```Enumerator```, and yes ```IEnumerable<T>``` is perfectly valid syntax. However, it can have side effects that are not obvious, so I recommend using ```IList``` or ```IReadOnlyList``` instead, as it's usually closer to the intention. See also https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/PossibleMultipleEnumeration.html